# Graphite webapp only shows metrics from first of 4 caches

Tags: graphite

I have a graphite relay and webapp installed on one servers, that is supposed to be communicating with 4 carbon caches (and respective webapps) on 4 other servers. I've validated that the relay is working by observing that different whisper files are being updated on different carbon-relay servers.

However, the webapp is only showing metrics that are stored on the first carbon cache server in the list and I'm not sure what else to look at.

The webapps on the carbon relays are set up to listen on port 81, and I have the following in local_settings.py on the relay server (the one I'm pointing my browser at):

```
CLUSTER_SERVERS = ["graphite-storage1.mydomain.com:81", "graphite-storage2.mydomain.com:81", "graphite-storage3.mydomain.com:81", "graphite-storage4.mydomain.com:81", ]
```

However - at one point I did have all metrics on all servers - I've migrated from a single instance to this federated cluster. I've since removed the whisper files that weren't active on each carbon-cache server. I've restarted all carbon-caches, the carbon-relay and the webapp server several times. Is there somewhere the metrics-->carbon-cache mapping is getting cached? Have I missed a setting somewhere?

Comment: which version of graphite do you use ? there is no persistent cache in ~0.9.10